# Nativescript Camera Plus photoCapturedEvent not called and image not saving to library nativescript+vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to implement the nativescript-camera-plus plugin to take an image. I am developing an IOS (for iPad) application with NativeScript + vue and am using an emulator to test.

For some reason the photoCapturedEvent event is not been triggered when the `takePicture()` is called. Furthermore, when `{ saveToGallery: true }` is been passed through this method, the image is not saved to the photo gallery.

The loaded event works and runs as the component is loaded. I am unsure if the `errorEvent` event gets triggered.

Here is a snippet of my code (in `TakePhoto.vue`):

```
<CameraPlus ref="CameraPlus" height="600" id="camPlus"
                saveToGallery="true"      
                showCaptureIcon="true"
                showGalleryIcon="false"
                showToggleIcon="false"       
                showFlashIcon="false"
                debug="true"
                enableVideo="false"
                confirmVideo="false"
                defaultCamera="front" 
                @loaded="onCameraLoaded"
                @photoCapturedEvent="photoCaptured($event)"
                @errorEvent="onCameraError">     
</CameraPlus>
```

And here is the associated methods

```
onCameraLoaded(result) {
    this.cam = result.object;
    console.log("Camera loaded...");
},

onButtonCapture() {
    console.log('Take Picture');
    this.image = this.cam.takePicture({ saveToGallery: true });     
},

photoCaptured(args){
    console.log("ARGS - ", args)
},
```

I would also like to mention that I have registered the component in the app.js file like so: `Vue.registerElement('CameraPlus', () => require('@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus').CameraPlus);`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it iOS / Android? Do you the see the camera output on your screen?

Comment: Hey, it's iOS, and all I see in the emulator is a black screen for where the component is (it does not take up the whole screen).

Comment: **Emulator**? Camera doesn't work on iOS Simulators.

Comment: I am aware that the camera does not work on iOS emulators, but wouldn't it still just give me a blank image along with firing off the event and saving a blank (black) image to the photo gallery?

Comment: No it won't, at least on iOS Simulator.